# Tkinter root.geometry overrides root.pack_propagate

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text, size

Tkinter `root.geometry` overrides `root.pack_propagate`, so this causes window to not resize via child widgets. How can i create window with some geometry, which will be bigger than `minsize`, and which will not override `propagate` method?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=50, height=50)
root.geometry('100x50')
root.pack_propagate(True)

text = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=10)

text.pack()
text.insert('end', 'veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long text')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It may be unrelated to your question, but are you aware that `width=50` in the `minsize` call is in pixels, but the `width=50` in the creation of the text widget is in characters? 50 characters is going to be considerably wider than 50 pixels unless you're using a 1-pixel wide font.

Comment: Why don't you just set `root.minsize(width=100, height=50)` and remove `root.geometry(...)`?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, i know about the difference. It's a simplified example. In real program i have a text widget, which shows/hides by pressing on the window by mouse. so, i need to resize the window when showing the text widget to adjust the contents of it and resize it back when i hide the text widget. It's not so complicated, but i thought that it's possible by built-in methods.

Comment: @acw1668 i can, but than i will not be able to make the window smaller. I need to resize the window by myself + set small minsize + set normal (lookable) default geometry + make window resizeble by it's contents. So, i think i ll write a simple function, which will override resize rules

Comment: _" i need to resize the window when showing the text widget to adjust the contents of it and resize it back when i hide the text widget."_ - it would be best if you add that in the question itself.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to a show a widget and let tkinter resize the window, and how to hide the widget and restore the fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i create window with some geometry, which will be bigger than minsize, and which will not override propagate method?

If I understand what you're asking -- and there's a good chance I don't -- the answer is "you can't". As you observed, if you call the `geometry` method, your window will be that size. That is the defined behavior. *Either* you set a size using `geometry`, or you allow `grid` and/or `pack` set the size based on the contents of the window.

---

In a comment you wrote:

> i need to resize the window when showing the text widget to adjust the contents of it and resize it back when i hide the text widget.

To do that, you can call `geometry` and pass it an empty string. It will then remove the forced size, and let the window resize based on its contents. To give a good user experience you should probably remember the previous geometry so you can restore it later.

Here's an example. It relies on global variables so it's not the best way to implement it, but it is good enough to illustrate the concept.

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_text():
    global geometry
    if text.winfo_viewable():
        text.pack_forget()
        if geometry:
            root.geometry(geometry)
    else:
        geometry = f"{root.winfo_width()}x{root.winfo_height()}"
        root.geometry("")
        text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x50')
text = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=10)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Toggle Text", command=toggle_text)
button.pack(side="top", padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

When you run this you'll get a small window with a button. Clicking the button will add or remove the text widget. When the widget is removed, the previous window size is restored. When it is added, the window will automatically resize to fit the contents.

Before pressing the button, or after pressing it when the text widget was visible:

[image: screenshot before pressing the button]

After pressing the button when the text widget isn't visible:

[image: screenshot after pressing the button]

You can manually resize the original window, and the size you give it will be restored when the text widget is removed.

Comment: This is the best answer! Really works on me. I recalculated TextW size by font calculating, to apply writing every line without word-wrapping (for better experience bc TextW will display cmd like text (not too long, but long enough to stretch TextW a bit)). Thank you again for your help! really appreciate. Wish you all best!